# How do I link an installed C library to Octave to create new, Octave callable functions?

Tags: c, matlab, linker, octave, mex

The installed library is [ta-lib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ta-lib/) which, on my Linux system, consists of five header files

- ta_abstract.h
- ta_common.h
- ta_defs.h
- ta_func.h
- ta_libc.h

in the directory /usr/include/ta-lib, and in the directory /usr/lib there are

- libta_lib.a
- libta_lib.la
- libta_lib.so
- libta_lib.so.0
- libta_lib.so.0.0.0

which results from the normal ./configure, make and then checkinstall to install the ta_lib library.

Over on the [MATLAB Mathworks forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34744-ta-lib-mex-functions-and-oslion-binaries#functions_tab) a user has provided a compileMex.m script to link/compile, with a typical line such as

```
mex TA_ADOSC.c -I"../src/TA_COMMON/" -I"../include/" -L"../src/.libs/" -l"ta_lib"
```

When I try the above command, after changing the paths to match my ta_lib installation, I get the error

```
gcc: error: TA_ADOSC.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

which I can understand as the TA_ADOS.c is not it's own file but is code contained within the ta_func.h header file.

Basically my question is "What is the equivalent Octave 'mkoctfile' command, or whatever, for the above MATLAB mex command(s) such that I can link Octave against the installed ta_lib library and call the library's functions as I would a normal octave .m function or a compiled .oct function?"

Comment: This doesn't seem like it has anything to do with matlab or octave. The linked library seems like something provided in a number of environments, including a .jar file for java, and .tar.gz for c.  If you want a c++ interface download the .tar.gz and compile using the given makefile. If you'd like to use the java interface, download the .jar file. There are ways to use both from within octave; the java interface will probably be easier.

Comment: Have you tried just using octave's `mex` command?

Comment: Have you tried the given `mex` command in Octave? If so, and it didn't work, please provide error messages etc.